# Trying to install meteor on centos 5

Tags: centos, meteor

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

Trying to run this command to install meteor:

```
curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

```
============= Output Error ===============
Installing /tmp/meteor-install-Nv47529/meteor-0.3.6-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6)(64bit) is needed by meteor-0.3.6-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by meteor-0.3.6-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit) is needed by meteor-0.3.6-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) is needed by meteor-0.3.6-1.x86_64
Installation failed.
============= Output Error ===============
```

glib is missing showing but check glib using

```
rpm -qa --qf="%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n" | grep glibc | sort
```

showing me

```
compat-glibc-2.3.4-2.26.i386
compat-glibc-2.3.4-2.26.x86_64
compat-glibc-headers-2.3.4-2.26.x86_64
glibc-2.5-49.el5_5.7.i686
glibc-2.5-49.el5_5.7.x86_64
glibc-common-2.5-49.el5_5.7.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.5-49.el5_5.7.i386
glibc-devel-2.5-49.el5_5.7.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.5-49.el5_5.7.x86_64
glibc-utils-2.5-49.el5_5.7.x86_64
```

so any idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`GLIBC_2.6` is required by the RPM, you only have `GLIBC_2.5` so you need to upgrade.

Alternatively, this dependency may be more strict than it needs to be; try packing Meteor yourself.

Comment: I'd love to know what specifically requires glibc 2.6+ as most RHEL or their kin all support only 2.5 to this point. Not planning a huge jump to Centos 6 any time soon. http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos

Comment: @JeffreyGilbert: Don't confuse SO version with package version, see http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.5) and http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6); so, yes, you'll need to upgrade to a newer distro version or pack Meteor yourself assuming such a recent version is not necessarily needed. I don't know more details as to why the dependency is in place for the rpm, it may be meaningless...

Comment: I know it means I had to upgrade my distro to Centos 6 which I'm currently lamenting as some legacy software can't access MySQL now. It almost went smoothly until it didnt.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604040/glibc-2-7-error-updating-node-js-on-centos