# GLIBC_2.7 error updating node.js on CentOS

Tags: node.js, centos, glibc

I am trying to update the version of Node installed on a server. The version that was on there prior was 0.2.5 or something like that, so it was quite old. After some reading around I found that executing `n stable` would install the latest version of Node. Upon it's supposed installation, and now when I enter `node -V`, the console returned:

> node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)

So now I need to figure out how to fix that. I found [a page describing installation](http://midnightcodr.github.io/blog/2012/11/22/install-node-dot-js-v0-dot-8-14-onto-centos-5-howto/), but the article says to make sure that you compile the files specific to the server architecture. I'm not sure how to verify mine, and the last thing I want to do is botch something installing 32bit over 64bit or vice-versa.

Does anybody have an alternate method of fixing this issue overall, or some suggestions on verifying my server architecture so I can proceed with installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who comes across this, apparently the issue is that I am running Centos 5.2, which comes stock with python 2.4. To be able to update successfully via `npm` you need a higher version of python. Instead of going via `npm` I did the following:

To create an alternate install of Python 2.7 alongside 2.4, follow the instructions [here](http://justintallant.com/installing-node-on-centos/):

```
# cd /opt
# wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
# tar -xf Python-2.7.3.tgz
# cd Python-2.7.3
# yum install gcc
# ./configure
# make
# make altinstall
```

Don't install 2.7 over 2.4, because apparently that causes a bunch of features of the OS to stop working. This is the function of `altinstall`.

For the installation of node itself, the `wget` in those instructions is old, so follow [these instructions](http://lexsheehan.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-install-nodejs-on-centos.html?showComment=1365615164374#c2028854505934346831):

```
# mkdir ~/sources
# cd ~/sources
# wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
# tar zxvf node-latest.tar.gz
# cd node-v<TAB>
# python2.7 ./configure
# make
# make install
# mv /root/sources/node-v0.10.1/out/Release /opt/node-v0.10.1
# ln -s /opt/node-v0.10.1/node /usr/bin/node
```

Be sure to replace the version number in the last two steps with whichever one was installed via node-latest-tar.gz. Also note that the original instructions don't include `python2.7` before `./configure`, but the code will not function otherwise, assuming you followed the first part to create the `altinstall` of python 2.7